# Does ‘legit intel” pass as a usual English word?

Tags: meaning, contemporary-english

I found the word, “legit intel” in the following sentence of Maureen Dowd’s article titled “[Shadow of a Doubt](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/09/04/opinion/dowd-shadow-of-a-doubt.html?hp)” in today’s (September 3) New York Times.

> “Once more, we’re vociferously debating whether to slap down a murderous dictator who has gassed his own people, and whether we have **the legit intel** to prove he used W.M.D.
>
> Many around the president are making the case that if he doesn’t stand firm on his line in the sand, having gotten so far out on a limb, he’ll look weak and America will lose face and embolden its foes.”

Though Google Ngram shows no incidence of “legit intel,” I surmise it is an abbreviated form of legitimate intelligence from the context.

Does the phrase have currency?  If so, is it more common in writing or in day-to-day conversation?  If not, is it simply a part of Ms. Dowd's idiolect?

Comment: Also, can we start a "Dowd-ism" tag?  To be used primarily by you, I think ... // Also, although I approve of your changing "popular" to "familiar", you messed up the grammar of your last sentence.

Comment: Hunter 2. As I wrote before, I use to skim several English journals every morning, partly for picking up words and phrases I’m not familiar with, or I feel odd. Unfortunately there’s no one else than Dowd who constantly provides me with so many stuff for this purpose. As long as she is at work, I don’t have to worry about the paucity of materials for keeping posting questions in EL&U. I buy and heartily second your unique proposition to establish “Dowd idiolect” tag in the site in the honor of the fertility goddess of English neologism if it’ possible, as its sole beneficiary.

Comment: Oishi san, your words bring me more joy than those of most NES. // That comment would need the '@-tag' to be delivered to me. // To be unnecessarily semi-serious: they are, as you say, often *neologisms*; Dowd is the *only* source, because she makes them up willy-nilly. Granted, you/we turn them into good 'launching points' and interesting discussion, but she's not (from your Questions) a good source of phrases that are new to you as an ESL-er - they're new to everyone, they're not standard English. / I will (again, I think) suggest the New Yorker and the Economist for current well-written ...

Comment: ...  periodicals.   There are a number of authors whose wordplay you might enjoy and find pontifical.  I'm sure others can join in, but some of the big (old) names are: Oscar Wilde, Mark Twain, Cole Porter, Noel Coward.   Christopher Buckley, David Sedaris, and anything published by McSweeney are more current (by the better part of a century), and more familiar / colloquial, as opposed to the explicit wordplay of the former group.

Answer (score 9):

*Legit intel* is not a fixed phrase. It's just a couple of informal words used together:

- **legit:** legitimate, respectable
- **intel:** intelligence (in the reconnaissance sense)

Comment: They aren't really "used together" at all, just used in succession, it's not a "phrase".  It is perfectly legit American language.  The meaning of the sentences however. . . .

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the answers currently posted - "legit intel" is not a fixed idiom.

Interestingly, perhaps, we have a choice:

- "legit" as current slang (as in @Rye's Answer), meaning 'true, pure, or of notable positive quality - though possibly not the highest'.   "This is a *legit* party." "They're not studio quality, but these are some legit headphones for casual listening."
- or "legit" as an abbreviation of the more traditional sense (as in @Brad's Answer) - 'legit intel' as opposed to 'fake, forged, illegitimate intel'

IMO, either fits Dowd's context ...

Comment: To clarify (as mentioned in a comment further down), the first of these would be an antonym of *lame*, *mediocre*, or *inadequate* / the second would be an antonym of *fake* or *inauthentic*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the phrase itself is common.  "Legit" being slang used younger crowds and hardly ever hitting anything that has an audience over 25.  "Intel" is more common but I would say it is mainly used by older crowds - in a business/work environment.

So they are slang/abbreviations used by, in my opinion, two different groups.  And in the context of this article I don't think they make sense.  If you are going to use the word vociferously then spell out legitimate intelligence.

Side note: The slang word "legit" has almost a half meaning of "cool".  If my 16 year old says that something is "legit" he is saying something is "good/respectable/cool".  It doesn't fit with "intel".  Well unless the "intel" came from MC Hammer...

[image]

Comment: Your 16-year-old listens to (or even _knows_) MC Hammer?!

Comment: Stop. Hammertime!

Comment: -1 *Legit* is perfectly acceptable and understandable (to over 25's) as an abbreviation for *legitimate* (at least in the UK), so saying that the two terms are "used by ... two different groups" is nonsense.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Hammer was on some TV show and my 2 oldest did download a couple of his songs.  Just a few weeks ago I asked my 14 year old to quit putting his feet on the coffee table and he did answer back "I am 2 legit 2 quit."

Comment: @TrevorD - I didn't say it wasn't understandable.  I said contextually you would hear "legit" often used for under 25.  If I had a powerpoint presentation and it was titles 10 Legit Reasons to Switch Providers - my employees would roll their eyes at me.  I just messaged two girls I have working for me in London.  They giggled when I used legit.  Hey I will use it and I will wear the parachute pants.

Comment: I'm with TrevorD on this one. I hear my 40-year-old friends use _legit_ (especially “Seems legit!”), whereas my 19-year-old daughter would roll her eyes. This is in California.

Comment: What I'm trying to say in my answer is that there are two slightly different meanings/nuances - *legit*, ''not *fake*'' and *legit*, ''not lame, not bad''. / I know what Rye means, I feel like "This is a legit party." is fairly informal and 'young' - but I guess it *is* the same sense in which Hammer used it, so ... we're all getting old?

Comment: @BraddSzonye - I have friends that say "bro" and might say legit.  Just because an older adult says something doesn't mean it isn't usually used by younger crowds.  Also just because something is used by younger crowds doesn't mean older people don't understand it.  My kids say a lot of stupid phrases and I probably know too much younger slang.  Doesn't mean I could go to work and say it without eyes rolling.  - And yes every time a friend says "bro" I am embarrassed for them.

Comment: I'm just saying, your experience may not be universal. You should probably not condemn the style of a Pulitzer-winning journalist simply because it doesn't match the vocabulary that you and your bros use. ;)

Comment: @BraddSzonye You mean, because there are more compelling reasons to condemn her style?

Comment: @hunter2 If you've got compelling reasons, then please post them. It would be much better than the anecdotal evidence given here.

Comment: The first part of the sentence set a tone.  The second part doesn't make sense in the context of the initial tone.  It sounds like the author is just trying to fit in some "cool/trendy" abbreviations so that she sounds more up-to-date.

Comment: @BraddSzonye - I do like to see the upvotes on your answer.  You had no opinion and really just provided the obvious.

Comment: @RyeBread I frankly find it bizarre that you find either _legit_ or _intel_ “cool” or “trendy,” especially given that you're citing a rap artist whose popularity peaked over 20 years ago. I get what you're trying to say – it just seems like you're undermining your own evidence. (And I don't get what you're saying about my answer. Do you have a constructive comment to make about it?)

Comment: @BraddSzonye "more" - it's fairly subjective - plenty of people are bound to dislike her style. Her Pulitzer is largely irrelevant; there are far too many Pulitzer winners for anyone to like them all, and as a quick perusal of things said by Nobel laureates will confirm, relying on appeal to authority (of winning a prestigious award) remains a folly.

Comment: *That said* - what I say in my second comment to OP is a reason some find her uncompelling, if not condemnable. She mixes metaphors and breaks idioms with reckless abandon. Sort of as Rye's 'cool/trendy' comment sugests, she seems to have a lot of 'forced' puns/jokes/wordplay. 'Groaners', if you will. I say this mostly based on OPs other Qs from her writing. // (Cool down - I think he's just saying he likes your answer, as a clear, objective answer.)

Comment: @BraddSzonye - I was using sarcasm.  I was showing that using a word like vociferously and then another that Hammer made common vernacular just seemed silly.  Silly like you taking my Hammer picture serious.

Comment: Eh, I find the whole passage playful, _vociferously_ and all. And I'm still having trouble reconciling your claims that "Hammer made [it] common vernacular" 20 years ago with your claims that it's a word for the 20-something crowd. Or is that sarcasm again? It doesn't play well in text. (And while I am a very silly person, when you say it like that, it smells like a personal attack. Please be civil.)

Comment: @BraddSzonye - No attack.  You bring up valid points and I have my opinion. I just was playing off of the fact when I hear the word "legit" I think "2 legit 2 quit".  And when I brought the word up at work - before my post - two colleagues made Hammertime references.  And my comments on your answer certainly wasn't negative to what you put, but maybe so to the voters.  They should be looking for something more than a common definition right?